# Convert event records to periods with sums

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'EventTime' : ['2019-06-03 09:51:05', '2019-06-03 09:55:07',
       '2019-06-03 10:02:00', '2019-06-03 10:06:00',
       '2019-06-03 10:07:00', '2019-06-03 10:20:00',
       '2019-06-03 10:29:59', '2019-06-03 09:51:00',
       '2019-06-03 09:52:00'],
    'Status' : ['NotWorking', 'Working', 'NotWorking', 'Working', 'NotWorking',
       'Working', 'Working', 'NotWorking', 'Working']
             })
df
```

[image]

Each record represents an event that has happened at EventTime.
I have to find out how many seconds were each customer in each state within 15 minutes intervals. 
Sounds complicated, isn't it?

For example, for Customer A at 2019-06-03 09:51:05, Status is changed to NotWorking.
For this record 15 minutes period is 2019-06-03 09:45:00 - 2019-06-03 09:59:59.

For records that don't have previous records, previous Status is Working.
So, for 15 minutes interval that starts at 2019-06-03 09:45:00 until 2019-06-03 09:51:05, we have 365 seconds in Status Working.

Now from 2019-06-03 09:51:05 to next record for the same Customer 2019-06-03 09:55:07 we have 242 seconds in Status NotWorking.

From 2019-06-03 09:55:07 to end of 15 minutes period 2019-06-03 09:59:59 we have 292 + 1 = 293 seconds in Status (still) Working.

So firs record for Customer A and 15 minutes period that starts at 2019-06-03 09:45:00 record looks like this:

A   2019-06-03 09:45:00   Working = 365 + 293 = 658, NotWorking= 242

Now we have another 15 minutes period that starts at 2019-06-03 10:00:00.
From 2019-06-03 10:00:00 until 2019-06-03 10:02:00 there are 120 seconds in Status Working.
From 2019-06-03 10:02:00 until 2019-06-03 10:06:00 there are 240 seconds in Status NotWorking.
From 2019-06-03 10:06:00 until 2019-06-03 10:07:00 there are 60 seconds in status Working.
From 2019-06-03 10:07:00 until end of 15 minutes period 2019-06-03 10:14:59 there are 479 + 1 = 480 seconds in Status NotWorking.

So, next recor for Customer A and 15 minutes period 2019-06-03 10:00:00 is:

A   2019-06-03 10:00:00   Working = 120 + 60 = 180, NotWorking = 240 + 480= 720.

Output should be

- A   2019-06-03 09:45:00   Working = 658, NotWorking = 242
- A   2019-06-03 10:00:00   Working = 180, NotWorking = 720

Is it posible to do such calculation with pandas?

Regards.

EDIT: This should be the end result

[image]

I have done it like this, but I think it could be done in better way.

```
def start_of_15_min(event_datetime):
    minute = event_datetime.minute
    if minute >= 45:
        new_minute=45
    elif minute >= 30:
        new_minute=30
    elif minute >= 15:
        new_minute=15        
    elif minute >= 0:
        new_minute=0  

    new_event_datetime = datetime.datetime(event_datetime.year, event_datetime.month, event_datetime.day, event_datetime.hour, new_minute, 0)
    return new_event_datetime

def end_of_15_min(event_datetime):

    start_of_15_min_per = start_of_15_min(event_datetime)

    return start_of_15_min_per + datetime.timedelta(seconds=899)



# In[308]:


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'Status' : ['NotWorking', 'Working', 'NotWorking', 'Working', 'NotWorking',
       'Working', 'Working', 'NotWorking', 'Working'],
    'EventTime' : ['2019-06-03 09:51:05', '2019-06-03 09:55:07',
       '2019-06-03 10:02:00', '2019-06-03 10:06:00',
       '2019-06-03 10:07:00', '2019-06-03 10:20:00',
       '2019-06-03 10:29:59', '2019-06-03 09:51:00',
       '2019-06-03 09:52:00'],
             })
df.EventTime = pd.to_datetime(df.EventTime)
df


# In[310]:


df.groupby('Customer').EventTime.agg(['min', 'max']).applymap(start_of_15_min)


# In[311]:


for idx, row in df.groupby('Customer').EventTime.agg(['min', 'max']).applymap(start_of_15_min).iterrows():
    for event_time in pd.date_range(start=row['min'], end=row['max'], freq='15T'):
        if len(df[(df.Customer == idx) & (df.EventTime == event_time)]) == 0:
            new_row = pd.DataFrame({'Customer' : idx, 'Status': np.nan, 'EventTime' : event_time}, index=[0])
            df = df.append(new_row)
df = df.sort_values(['Customer', 'EventTime']).reset_index(drop=True)
df


# In[313]:


df.Status = df.groupby('Customer').Status.fillna(df.groupby('Customer').Status.shift())
df


# In[314]:


df.Status = df.Status.fillna('Working')
df


# In[315]:


for idx, row in df.groupby('Customer').EventTime.agg(['min', 'max']).applymap(end_of_15_min).iterrows():
    for event_time in pd.date_range(start=row['min'], end=row['max'], freq='15T'):
        if len(df[(df.Customer == idx) & (df.EventTime == event_time)]) == 0:
            new_row = pd.DataFrame({'Customer' : idx, 'Status': np.nan, 'EventTime' : event_time}, index=[0])
            df = df.append(new_row)
df = df.sort_values(['Customer', 'EventTime']).reset_index(drop=True)
df


# In[316]:


df.Status = df.groupby('Customer').Status.fillna(df.groupby('Customer').Status.shift())
df


# In[317]:


df['Seconds'] = df.groupby('Customer').EventTime.apply(lambda x: (x.shift(-1) - x).dt.seconds)
df


# In[318]:


df['StartOf15Minutes'] = df.EventTime.apply(start_of_15_min)
df


# In[319]:


df.Seconds = df.Seconds.fillna(1)
df


# In[320]:


fin = df.groupby(['Customer', 'StartOf15Minutes', 'Status']).Seconds.sum().to_frame()
fin


# In[305]:


fin.Seconds.sum()
```

Comment: Value 657 is correct. Expected value for B and 09:45:00 is Working = 360 + 479 = 839, and NotWorking = 60.

Comment: Please give to me some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is created helper DataFrames for first duplicates rows and last, change datetimes by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df['EventTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EventTime'])

df1 = df.drop_duplicates('Customer').copy()
#swap values
df1['Status'] = df1['Status'].map({'NotWorking':'Working','Working':'NotWorking'})
df1['EventTime'] = df1['EventTime'].dt.floor('15T')

df2 = df.drop_duplicates('Customer', keep='last').copy()
df2['EventTime'] = df2['EventTime'].dt.floor('15T') + pd.Timedelta(60 * 15, 's')

df = pd.concat([df, df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Then fet seconds by resample with `ffill` per groups, remove last values per groups and aggregate `size` for sum of seconds:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('EventTime')
          .groupby('Customer')
          .resample('s').ffill())
df1 = df1[df1.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep='last')]


df1 = (df1.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
          .groupby(['Customer', 'Status', pd.Grouper(freq='15T')])
          .size())
```

---

```
print (df1)
Customer  Status      EventTime          
A         NotWorking  2019-06-03 09:45:00    242
                      2019-06-03 10:00:00    720
                      2019-06-03 10:15:00    300
          Working     2019-06-03 09:45:00    658
                      2019-06-03 10:00:00    180
                      2019-06-03 10:15:00    600
B         NotWorking  2019-06-03 09:45:00     60
          Working     2019-06-03 09:45:00    840
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have looking for. Thanks.